# Not passing up a mitzvah: putting away laundry at a parent's behest: closest pile first?

Tags: halacha, clothing, priorities, kibbud-av-veim-honoring, cleaning

My kid asked:

> I know there's a general rule of *en maavirin al hamtizvos*, we don't pass over a *mitzva*. For example, in *mishnayos Yoma*, the *kohanim* don't pass over the nearest blood basin to put blood in a farther basin. Let's say I'm putting away piles of folded laundry because my parent told me to [thereby fulfilling the *mitzva* of *mora av vaem*]. Do I have to put away the nearest pile first [since putting each pile away is a *mitzva* and passing up the nearest pile is passing over a *mitzva*]?

(It seems reasonable to me that the answer is "Yes", but I don't know the parameters of *en maavirin*.)

Answer (score 1):

Tosafos defines Ein Ma'avirim - one shouldn't pass over a Mitzvah to do another one - in Zevachim (זבחים נ. ד"ה אשר פתח‏) Tosafos as one of 2 possibilities.

- When one has the option of doing 2 Mitzvoth, one does the closest one first
- When one has a Mitzvah spread over an area one begins with the closest spot.

> דלא שייך אין מעבירין על המצות אלא כשיש שתי מצות לפניו כגון דישון מזבח פנימית ומנורה או כגון מצות קרנות שאינו יודע מהיכן יתחיל... ‏

The Tosafos in Megila (מגילה ו: ד"ה מסתבר‏) concurs.

> ויש מפרשים דלא שייך למימר אין מעבירין על המצות אלא היכא שיש לפניו שתי מצות שיש לו לעשות קודם אותה דפגע ברישא וזה אינו דהכא ליכא אלא מצוה אחת ואפילו הכי מפרש הטעם משום דאין מעבירין... ‏

Rashi ibid (ד"ה אין מעבירין) says that the source of Ein Ma'avirim is from the Torah!

> **אין מעבירין כו'**. משבא לידי אקדים לעשות דהכי תניא במכילתא ושמרתם את המצות אם באת מצוה לידך אל תחמיצנה‏

And Tosafos (ibid) brings an opinion that Ein Ma'avirim is not only Lechatchila, but also B'dieved (ex post facto) it applies. I.e. one cannot choose to ignore it as *it's only a good thing to do*.

> ורבינו יהודה תירץ דאי לאו קרא הוה אמינא דאין מעבירין לכתחילה הא דיעבד שרי משום הכי איצטריך דאסור בדיעבד‏

Since I cannot find anybody else who defines Ein Ma'avirim and no examples to the contrary, it would seem that the nearest pile of laundry should be taken care of first.